# How do I write algorithm below code in python?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a word = x
I want to write a code :

If the word (x) is in the data frame (A), create a data frame(B) with the value of 'Yes' in front of it (in the cell with the same number).

Comment: Can you show an example or elastration of the desired output?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eXvQyCdQl9WQieEggZrGZbYFX8D3WHEY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to write a code: if the word 'covidvaccine' is in each cell, label it with "yes", else "no"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture (and edit the Q itself instead of adding comments). E.g. try `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` condition to find and string matching.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
   
# a sample dictionary to create dataframe
data = [{'colA': 'Covid', 'colB': 'test', 'colC': 'test02'},
        {'colA':'nothing', 'colB': 'happened', 'colC': 'to them'}]
# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,index=['1', '2'])

df['new_col'] = np.where(df['colA'].str.contains('Covid'), 'Yes', 'No') 
print(df)
```

The output is as follow:

```
      colA      colB     colC   new_col
1    Covid      test   test02     Yes
2  nothing  happened  to them      No
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I want to search in the "hashtags" data frame to find the word "CovidVaccine". I don't want to create it manually

Comment: Just apply the condition on your own dataframe. You did not provided any sample df to experiment. Change the word "Covid" to "CovidVaccine".

Comment: appreciate youuuu buddy!